# Google fonts working on live server but not on localhost

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-fonts

My google fonts display fine on my live website, but in production on localhost, they show differently. More boxy/standard, but not the same as the standard font.

How they show on localhost:

[image: How they show on localhost]

How they show on live server (this is want I want):

[image: How they show on live server]

Here's my CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans|Caveat+Brush');

body{ 
  font-family: "Droid Sans", sans-serif; //'projects'
}
#title {
  font-family: 'Caveat Brush', cursive; //'Junior Web Developer'
}
```

I am using `gulp` and `browser-sync`, but opening the html file directly from the browser has the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the @import code to the very top of your CSS file above everything else.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans|Caveat+Brush');
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. The import was at the top of the file that it was it, but gulp was concatenating my files together and it ended up not at the top of the complied css file.

Comment: Movin on top has not worked for me, any other solution?

Comment: In my case, one of my parameters was ill defined which invalidated the URL, make sure your @import URL resolves itself, if it doesn't fix it and try again, could solve your problem (it did for me).